# How to find total number of dominant sets for a given graph?

Tags: graph-theory

Is there any efficient algorithm to find the total number of dominant sets for a given graph? For example, in the image shown, 
[A graph with three vertices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azTGC.png) has the following dominant sets: { {A, C}, {B}, {B, C}, {A, B}, {A,B,C} } giving a total of 5 dominant sets.

For another example, in the image below, 
[A graph with four vertices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COyPi.png) has the following dominant sets: { {A, B}, {A, C}, {A, D}, {B, C}, {B, D}, {C,D}, {A, B, C}, {A, B, D}, {A, C, D}, {B, C, D}, {A, B, C, D} } giving a total of 11 dominant sets. My question is to find this count (If there is any method to get count only without dominant sets is also fine).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks a lot for the references. I appreciate it.